# Encode sentence as sequence model with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, pyspark, text-classification

I am doing text classification and I use `pyspark.ml.feature.Tokenizer` to tokenize the text. However `CountVectorizer` transforms the tokenized list of words to bag of words model, not the sequence model.

Assume that we have the following DataFrame with columns id and texts:

```
 id | texts
----|----------
 0  | Array("a", "b", "c")
 1  | Array("a", "b", "b", "c", "a")
each row in texts is a document of type Array[String]. Invoking fit of CountVectorizer produces a CountVectorizerModel with vocabulary (a, b, c). Then the output column “vector” after transformation contains:

 id | texts                           | vector
----|---------------------------------|---------------
 0  | Array("a", "b", "c")            | (3,[0,1,2],[1.0,1.0,1.0])
 1  | Array("a", "b", "b", "c", "a")  | (3,[0,1,2],[2.0,2.0,1.0])
```

What I want here is (for the row 1)

```
Array("a", "b", "b", "c", "a")  | [0, 1, 1, 2, 0]
```

So is there anyway that I can write custom function to run encoding in parallel? Or is there any other library that can do in parallel other than using spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `StringIndexer` and `explode`:

```
df = spark_session.createDataFrame([
    Row(id=0, texts=["a", "b", "c"]),
    Row(id=1, texts=["a", "b", "b", "c", "a"])
])

data = df.select("id", explode("texts").alias("texts"))
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="texts", outputCol="indexed", stringOrderType="alphabetAsc")
indexer\
    .fit(data)\
    .transform(data)\
    .groupBy("id")\
    .agg(collect_list("texts").alias("texts"), collect_list("indexed").alias("vector"))\
    .show(20, False)
```

Output:

```
+---+---------------+-------------------------+
|id |texts          |vector                   |
+---+---------------+-------------------------+
|0  |[a, b, c]      |[0.0, 1.0, 2.0]          |
|1  |[a, b, b, c, a]|[0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0]|
+---+---------------+-------------------------+
```